# Graphql playground desktop app won't load

Tags: macos, graphql, apollo, graphql-playground

I was using the graphql playground desktop app on my Mac for a few months when it suddenly stopped working. Now , when I try to open the application, it gets stuck on this.
I uninstalled and reinstalled application but didn't help.

Any ideas?[image]